# Copying Sheet Data to Doc table

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a sheet with information that needs to be filled and once a submit process is started it should copy the cell data to an existing table header in a document. There is only one table in the document with the header info.

I can get this to work just fine with appendTable, but I would like to append rows to the existing table in the document. Data from spreadsheet looks like
 [[1234, Jordan, Connecticut], [6899123, Job Site, Connecticut], [, , ]]

```
//  Sheet Data
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]
var range = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow(),sheet.getLastColumn());
var rows = sheet.getLastRow()
var values = range.getValues();


var document = DocumentApp.openById(tmpl);
var body = document.getBody();
   body.replaceText('#{jobNum}', job);
var table = body.getTables()[0]

document.saveAndClose()
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have the values in the variable `values` and you also selected the first table in the document in the variable `table`, now you just need to to loop through your Array and append rows using [appendTableRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table#appendtablerow) and [appendTableCell()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table-row#appendtablecell)

Your loop should look like this:

```
  for (var row = 0; row < values.length; row++) {
    var newRow = table.appendTableRow(); // Append new Row
    for (var col = 0; col < values[row].length; col++) {
      newRow.appendTableCell(values[row][col]); // Append a Cell with the value
    }
  }
```

This will append a row at the end of the table you already have in the document.