# Using Google Apps Script to Copy from Google Sheets Data Table to Google Documents Table

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

**Is there a way to write a Google Apps Script in Google Docs to retrieve from Google Sheets a range limited to non-blank rows and display those rows as a table?**

I'm looking for a script to copy non-blank rows of data from a Google Sheets range of cells to a table in Google Documents using Google Apps Script (which I've limited experience with).

The data to be copied seem too large for linking directly to Google Documents so the Copy-Paste action from spreadsheet to document does not prompt a choice for linking the data.

Also the number of rows is dynamic so a fixed range wouldn't resolve the problem.  In the spreadsheet, I've used the `SORTN` function and set it to display ties so the size of the non-blank rows of the range changes.

I've started with the following code outline:

```
function myFunction() {

  // Get Google Sheet data
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = app.openById('SHEET_ID');
  var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = activeSheet.getRange("B4:D");

  // Position to paste data in Google Docs
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();

  // Build a table from the array.
  body.appendTable(cells);

}
```

This is closest question found on SE but doesn't answer this query:  [Copying Sheet Data to Doc table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38772013/copying-sheet-data-to-doc-table).

Comment: In order to correctly understand your situation, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet and sample Document including the input and output you expect? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: Here's a [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xKQGbgco9F8B6qyIYQyfC52dxajtOgjQMsgxrGI1rIw/).  Here's a [sample document table](https://docs.google.com/document/d/16kV91yvH3_BEc-MwwNPCVHo7z7zsBAHaq3_yLNASVwQ/)

Comment: Thank you for replying and providing the samples. I saw them. I noticed that the table in the Document is linked to the original Spreadsheet. In the current stage, the table created by Google Apps Script in the Document cannot be linked to the Spreadsheet. So if you want to update the table, the table is required to be updated by the script. How about this?

Comment: @Tanaike Right, for the current project, the tables from the Spreadsheet cannot be paste-linked into the Document as shown in the sample Document file.  I've updated the sample Documents file to reflect that by removing the link from the table.  I'm assuming this limitation is due to data size (which doesn't apply to the small sample file) and can only be accomplished with a Google Apps Script for large data sets.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- You want to copy the data range from Google Spreadsheet to Google Document as the table.

  - You want to append the table to the Google Document.
  - In this case, you don't want to include the empty rows of the bottom of sheet to the values.
  - In your situation, you are not required to link the original Spreadsheet to the table of Document.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

I could understand like above. If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Flow:

The flow of this sample script is as follows.

1. Retrieve the data range from Google Spreadsheet.

   - In this case, I used [getDataRegion(dimension)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getDataRegion(Dimension)).
2. Retrieve values, backgrounds and text styles using the range.
3. Append new table to Google Document with the values.
4. Set the format of cells.

#### Sample script:

From your script in your question, it supposes that the script is the container-bound script of Google Document. So in order to test the script, please put the following script to the container-bound script of Google Document you shared.

```
function myFunction() {
  // Get Google Sheet data
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("###");  // Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var range = sheet.getRange(4, 2, 1, 5).getDataRegion(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);
  var values = range.getValues();
  var backgroundColors = range.getBackgrounds();
  var styles = range.getTextStyles();

  // Position to paste data in Google Docs
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var table = body.appendTable(values);
  table.setBorderWidth(0);
  for (var i = 0; i < table.getNumRows(); i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < table.getRow(i).getNumCells(); j++) {
      var obj = {};
      obj[DocumentApp.Attribute.BACKGROUND_COLOR] = backgroundColors[i][j];
      obj[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = styles[i][j].getFontSize();
      if (styles[i][j].isBold()) {
        obj[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;
      }
      table.getRow(i).getCell(j).setAttributes(obj);
    }
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- In this sample script, the values of cells "B4:F" are retrieved from your shared Spreadsheet. So if you want to change this range, please modify above script.

#### References:

- [getDataRegion(dimension)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getDataRegion(Dimension))
- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [getBackgrounds()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getbackgrounds)
- [getTextStyles()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#gettextstyles)
- [appendTable()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#appendtablecells)
- [setAttributes(attributes)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table-cell#setattributesattributes)

### Added:

#### Issue for reflecting column width from Spreadsheet to Document:

It is possible to reflect the column width. But when the column width is set to Google Document, it seems that the result is different from that of the direct copy&paste the table, even when the unit is converted from Spreadsheet to Document.

In your shared Spreadsheet, the widths of column "B" to "F" are 21, 100, 100, 100 and 100 pixels, respectively. But it was found that when the table is manually copied from Spreadsheet to Document, each column width is changed from the original size. By this, unfortunately, when the column width of table is copied by the script, the result by manual copy cannot be replicated.

#### Sample script:

At the following sample script, the column width of Google Spreadsheet is copied to the table of Google Document.

```
function myFunction() {
  // Get Google Sheet data
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("###");  // Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var range = sheet.getRange(4, 2, 1, 5).getDataRegion(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);
  var values = range.getValues();
  var backgroundColors = range.getBackgrounds();
  var styles = range.getTextStyles();

  var colWidth = [];  // Added
  for (var col = 2; col <= 6; col++) {  // Added
    colWidth.push(sheet.getColumnWidth(col) * 3 / 4);
  }

  // Position to paste data in Google Docs
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var table = body.appendTable(values);
  table.setBorderWidth(0);

  colWidth.forEach(function(e, i) {table.setColumnWidth(i, e)});  // Added

  for (var i = 0; i < table.getNumRows(); i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < table.getRow(i).getNumCells(); j++) {
      var obj = {};
      obj[DocumentApp.Attribute.BACKGROUND_COLOR] = backgroundColors[i][j];
      obj[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = styles[i][j].getFontSize();
      if (styles[i][j].isBold()) {
        obj[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;
      }
      table.getRow(i).getCell(j).setAttributes(obj);
    }
  }
}
```

- When you run the script, you can see the created table is different from the manually copied table. So about the width of column, in the current stage, please give the values for manually setting `colWidth`. Or please adjust the column width of Document side by modifying the column width of Spreadsheet side. Or please use above script. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: This worked brilliantly.  Thanks.  The styles and fonts were carried over.  The only format that didn't copy over is the column width.  Is there a way to copy this to the pasted table?

Comment: @Catalyx Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks for the added script and the info re column size not copying.  It looks like much of the reason is because of Document's default cell padding in the table.  To resolve it, I added the following code:   ```obj[DocumentApp.Attribute.PADDING_LEFT] = 0;
      obj[DocumentApp.Attribute.PADDING_RIGHT] = 0;```  A better solution would be to autosize the table's column widths based on the widest cell in each column.  Is this possible?

Comment: @Catalyx Thank you for replying. About automatically resizing the column width of the table, when `setColumnWidth` is not used, the width is automatically set. But if this is not the direction you want, unfortunately, it seems that there are no methods for automatically resizing the column width in the Google Document service. I apologize for this.

Comment: Using ```PADDING_``` worked good enough to adjust the automated format applied to the table.  Much thanks again.