# Google Apps Script: Copy Google Sheets table to Google Docs as Linked Object

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

Is there an option to copy a Google Sheets table to a Google Doc as a Linked Object via Google Apps Script?
What I usually do manually:

1. Select Range in Google Sheet
2. Press Cmd + C
3. Go to Google Doc
4. Press Cmd + V
5. Select Paste as Linked Object

I want to automate this via Google Apps Script and have tried `appendTable()` or `insertTable()` but  they both just paste the Values of the Sheets Table but not the formatting. And the table is also not linked to the original Google Sheet.

Is there a way to do this?

If there's no built-in method for this, is there a way for GUI automation in Google Apps Script like with PyAutoGUI in Python?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Google Apps Script to Copy from Google Sheets Data Table to Google Documents Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59709400/using-google-apps-script-to-copy-from-google-sheets-data-table-to-google-documen)

Comment: Nop id did not, I think he/she meant that how to copy table from spreadsheet to document as a linked table , So that if someone update the sheet these values can also be updated.

Comment: As this question is unanswered, this feature is not available. You can create a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113) in issuetracker.