# Google Docs table - how to format table (cell) and open document in browser

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

With Google Sheets I created a calculation table which I want to copy to a quote template in Google Docs with Google Apps Script. For this I use the solution found here in this question: [Using Google Apps Script to Copy from Google Sheets Data Table to Google Documents Table.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59709400/using-google-apps-script-to-copy-from-google-sheets-data-table-to-google-documen/59710473#59710473)

I use (literally exactly) the first sample script, without taking care of column width, as this is not an issue for me.
The copying works great, but I still have a few problems:

1. all the cell values are copied as text, so in the Google Docs table I have to reformat some values in Euro
2. in the Google Docs table all the cells are left aligned, I need to right align the columns with Euro values
3. the script uses "body.appendTable(values)" to insert table data at the end of the document, but how can I determine where in the document I want to place the table?
4. once created the new document from the template I would like to open it directly in the browser

My script is bound to the Google Sheet document, where I start the script from a custom menu.
You can see the [calculation sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hi7hi4ZMB6VTMTtiRpRJPMwU8ShNO2KGqJlFMOA_RyE/edit?usp=sharing) and the [template here.](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1LC2VC2lZyhxjhTe2YH8yhknEIvPjSz1gMU5s0DfuQRE/edit?usp=sharing)

Hope to find someone who can help.

**EDIT** to answer questions from comments:

1. Hey J.G., maybe the problem wasn't explained well enough or I am not smart enough to handle the solutions you proposed:
   `setNumberFormat()` worked for me only on a spreadsheet, but I have to format the table in Google Docs document.
   With the `insertTable(childIndex, table)` I was able to insert the table only at the beginning or the end of the document. What am I missing?
2. OK, it places the table on line 5 in this case, tried also many other indexes and was able to come to the position I want it to be. But this is not reliable enough for me, because if the template changes (and it will change!) I have to find the right index again and change the script. Or is there a possibility to search for a keyword in the doc and get it's childIndex via script?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38490800/set-cell-format-with-google-apps-script Tells you how to set your columns as number format

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#inserttablechildindex,-cells Shows you how to insert a table into a gdoc at a location.

Comment: child index should be the number of the node where you are inserting it, if you use "5" what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issues 1-3 can be easily solved. Here is the working script:

#### Code:

```
function myFunction() {
  // Get Google Sheet data
  var ssId = 'sample sheet id';
  var docId = 'sample doc id';
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId);  // Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("DataFilter");
  var range = sheet.getRange(4, 1, 1, 5).getDataRegion(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);
  // to include euro signs
  var values = range.getDisplayValues();
  var backgroundColors = range.getBackgrounds();
  var styles = range.getTextStyles();

  // Position to paste data in Google Docs
  var body = DocumentApp.openById(docId).getBody();
  var numElements = body.getNumChildren();
  // if 'Table_goes_here' is not found, append to bottom
  var index = numElements;

  // var index = body.getChildIndex(body.findText('Table_goes_here').getElement().getParent());
  // index wasn't found using the code above for some reason, so doing loop instead
  for (var i = 0; i < numElements; i++) {
    var child = body.getChild(i);
    if (child.asText().getText() == 'Table_goes_here') {
      index = i;
      // remove child
      body.removeChild(child);
      break;
    }
  }
  // then insert your table
  var table = body.insertTable(index, values);
  table.setBorderWidth(0);
  for (var i = 0; i < table.getNumRows(); i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < table.getRow(i).getNumCells(); j++) {
      var obj = {};
      obj[DocumentApp.Attribute.BACKGROUND_COLOR] = backgroundColors[i][j];
      obj[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = styles[i][j].getFontSize();
      if (styles[i][j].isBold()) {
        obj[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;
      }
      // if euro sign is found in text, align right
      if (table.getRow(i).getCell(j).getText().includes('€')) {
        table.getRow(i).getCell(j).getChild(0).asParagraph().setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
      }
      table.getRow(i).getCell(j).setAttributes(obj);
    }
  }
}
```

#### start of table:

[image: start]

#### end of table:

[image: end]

#### Note:

- Issue 4 is a tricky one. Apps Script cannot easily communicate with the browser (afaik) since this runs on the server side, not client. You can try showing the document on a [WebApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) instead.

#### Resources:

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/horizontal-alignment
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#inserttablechildindex,-cells

Comment: Hey NaziA, it's only easy if you know how to solve! Your script works perfect for me (upvoted!) and I learned a few new things today. For the doc to open in browser I will see at a later time. Thank you very much.